# MDX: joining two sets on same member of several dimensions?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

Is is possible in MDX to combine results of two queries based on the same member of several dimensions?

In my case:
There are two types of reports BuyersReports and SellersReports, e.g

BuyersReports

```
Buyer Seller Amount
A     B      10
B     C      20
```

SellersReports

```
Seller Buyer Amount
B      A     10
C      B     15
```

Each company (A,B,C) coulb be both buyer and seller.

I need to achieve some kind of this:

```
  Buy Sell-To (Diff1) Sell Buy-From (Diff2)
B 20  15      5       10   10        0
```

Currently I have two measures: [Buyings] and [Sellings], and two instances of the same dimension of companies: [Buyers] and [Sellers].

I can get both parts of the desired query for company "B":

```
SELECT 
[Measure].[Buyings],[Meausure].[Sellings] ON COLUMNS,
[Buyers].[Name], [Sellers].[Name] ON ROWS
FROM 
(
SELECT [Buyers].[Name].&[B] ON COLUMNS
FROM MyCube
)
```

gives me

```
B C 20 15
```

And

```
SELECT 
[Measure].[Buyings],[Meausure].[Sellings] ON COLUMNS,
[Buyers].[Name], [Sellers].[Name] ON ROWS
FROM 
(
SELECT [Sellers].[Name].&[B] ON COLUMNS
FROM MyCube
)
```

with result

```
A B 10 10
```

Is it possible to combine results of these two queries to achieve combined buyer-seller report for each company?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
[Measure].[Buyings],[Meausure].[Sellings] ON COLUMNS,
[Buyers].[Name], [Sellers].[Name] ON ROWS
FROM 
(
SELECT {[Sellers].[Name].&[B],SELECT [Buyers].[Name].&[B]}  ON COLUMNS
FROM MyCube
)
```